# Header Navmenu glitching in Chrome (but not other browsers)

Tags: menus, headers

My website, https://bthsensor.com has been experiecning a certain glitch on the chrome browser specifically. The header navigation menu jumps from its assigned position when the cursor hovers over it. Pics below (The first one is Chrome, where the glitch is visible, and the second on is Firefox):

[image: Chrome Glitch]

[image]

Where could this issue be coming from. I have tried various browsers including edge, firefox and safari, and it seems to be working just fine across those. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Prateek Pandey. As a rule, the community considers questions only about CSS or Javascript off-topic - which this might be. It may be better to see if this question would get more answers on [Webmaster SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36064/), perhaps. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but I found it was possible to reset the error by toggling `content: '';` in the `.col:after, .clr:after, .group:after, dl:after, .left_float:after, .right_float:after` rules set to off then on again. My guess is this is a browser-specific gotcha with this in some way.